# Since Upgrading, My NFS Mounts Are Hanging

Tags: nfs

Since upgrading my Ubuntu Machine, all my NFS mounts are hanging. I checked the syslog, and I'm seeing this now:

```
Sep 29 04:29:10 ip-10-10-10-10 kernel: [ 9589.594814] RPC: AUTH_GSS upcall failed. Please check user daemon is running.
```

All other methods of debugging NFS still show it up and running (telnet, rpcinfo, etc). What is the AUTH_GSS service and why does it need to be running? I've been running around on Google, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't already be going.

** UPDATE **

In addition to this, I'm now seeing the following on the server:

```
Sep 29 05:55:12 ip-10-10-10-10 rpc.gssd[860]: ERROR: can't open /run/rpc_pipefs/gssd/clntXX/info: No such file or directory
Sep 29 05:55:12 ip-10-10-10-10 rpc.gssd[860]: ERROR: failed to read service info
```

** UPDATE 2 **
I've tried disabling GSSD in the NFS settings, and no go. Further, I've manually run rpc.gssd, and that didn't do anything either.